# Calling a function exported by a DLL from an injected DLL

Tags: dll-injection

I need some hints to solve the following problem:

I have a simple VC++ app (called DLLApp) which loads a DLL (DLLSource) (with LoadLibrary) and calls an exported function ( __declspec(dllexport) int dllPublic_GetValue() ) from that DLL (which is simply printing a text).
I injected another DLL (called DLLHookSource) into DLLApp ( with CreateToolhelp32Snapshot and create thread on LoadLibraryA).
The injection is successfull, DLLHookSource loads, DLLApp calls the dllPublic_GetValue.

What I want to do next is to **call (again) the dllPublic_GetValue** (of DLLSource) from **DLLHookSource**, when DLLMain is called with DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH (in DLLHookSource).

I simply got confused reading a lot of info on the internet... I assume that I need to get PE's export table in order to get the *dllPublic_GetValue* pointer, or at least this was the closest info which would fit to what I need.
Therefore, my questions would be:

1. What are the steps for getting the pointer of *dllPublic_GetValue* (which belongs to DLLSource.dll) inside the Dllmain of the injected DLL named DLLHookSource?
2. What checks should be done in order to be sure that I'm the process (DLLApp.exe) space.

Thanks